# Deleting from Array but keep order?

Tags: java

Ok so im trying to delete an object from my array, each object has a user id, so the 0 index in array would hold an object with id one. when I delete object wih id of 2 for example I want to delete the 1 index in array and redo the model and display that. so I want the model to show 1:blah then 3:Blah and so on leaving out the deleted ones

```
 private void DeleteButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

// arrays index not working when deleted
int reply = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Are you sure?","Delete Patient: " +     
NameTextField.getText(), JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
    if (reply == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {

        int Num = Integer.parseInt(IDTextField.getText());
        int Num1 = Num--;


        for(Patient s: PatientList)
        {

            if(Num == s.getAccountNumber())
            {
                PatientList.remove(Num1);
                break;

            }
        }

        DefaultListModel PatientListModel = new DefaultListModel(); 

    for(Patient s: PatientList)
    {

   PatientListModel.addElement(s.getAccountNumber() + "-" + s.getName());  
 }
   PatientJList.setModel(PatientListModel); 

   //delete procedures for that id



      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Patient: " + NameTextField.getText() + "     

 Deleted!");
      NameTextField.setText("");
    AgeTextField.setText("");
    AddressTextField.setText("");
    SexGroup.clearSelection();
    PhoneTextField.setText("");
    IDTextField.setText("");
     PatientJList.clearSelection();


    }
    else {


    }
}
```

Comment: And your question is? Why don't you respect the Java naming conventions?

Answer (score 2):

I believe instead of using the array index as the object `id` you should be maintaing this property in the object itself. Something like:

```
public class Patient {

    private int id;

    // getter and setter for id

    // rest of the class

}
```

Comment: I do have that in the patient class, when deleting a object from the patientlist I loop through them and if the id num matches the num you enter to delete then get rid of num-1 in the patientlist.
Does that make sense?

Comment: At the time of display you can call `getId` instead of relying on array indices while iterating the list.

Answer (score 0):

the `Object` you are talking about, maintain one more property in it called `index`. While adding this object to array, set the `Object.index` to the index of array.

Now do whatever you want to the array. But at the time of displaying array. Do like this

`Object.index Object`